# Extensão Google Chrome - Adicionar marcadores sobre a pagina

Tags: google, google-chrome-extensão

existe alguma função ou maneira de adicionar pontos/objetos sobre a página em execução?

Minha ideia é permitir que o usuário da extensão possa clicar sobre a pagina e adicionar um marcador.

Comment: Com JavaScript injetado + API DOM (manipulação de HTML via javascript) + css é totalmente possível.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parece complexo, só achei exemplos em que a manipulação do html é predefinida direto no código =(.